# Cannot position a dialog at the center of the view

Tags: android, dialog, position, center

I want to put a custom dialog at the center point of a specific layout.
However the dialog does not go to the center. actually i tried various ways however now i am stuck... such a headache.
I tried like the code below.

```
showCustomDialog(){
            View view = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.abc, null);
            view.measure(view.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, view.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            LinearLayout BlackBox = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_layout);


            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

            params.x=blackBox.getMeasuredWidth()/2;
            params.y=blackBox.getMeasuredHeight()/2;
            System.out.println("params " + params.x +  " " + params.y);

            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(view.getMeasuredWidth(), WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cust_dialog);
            dialog.show();
    }
```

The thing is that i want to show the dialog at the center of the "txt_layout" named layout. 
Thanks for reading this..

Comment: Actually i checked that the params.y is working since the dialog looks as it is at the center(case Height) But for the width, the dialog is not positioning at the center of Width. sorry for my English

Comment: Try to add `dialog.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` or `center_vertical|center_horizontal`

Comment: @skizo i tried your method. the dialog is being showed at the center of the whole view. what is want is to make the dialog to be shown at the center of that txt_layout view ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this if you haven't tried before:

```
Window window = customdialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

And in the xml please check if you set this params:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="PauseDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/PauseDialogTitle</item>
        </style>

        <style name="PauseDialogTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle">
            <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        </style>
        <style name="DialogWindowTitle">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

And you layout should look like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 >
```

Comment: this is just a tutorial of how to make custom dialogs
please read my question